# Spring4 Ehcache

Tags: spring, ehcache

I'm trying to upgrade from spring 3.1 to spring 4.1,  but the Ehcache config encounter a problem. Below is exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name
 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0':
 Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
 convert property value of type
 'org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager' to required
 type 'net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager' for property 'cacheManager'; nested
 exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of
 type [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager] to
 required type [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager] for property
 'cacheManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found   at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 49 more Caused by:
 org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
 convert property value of type
 'org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager' to required
 type 'net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager' for property 'cacheManager'; nested
 exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of
 type [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager] to
 required type [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager] for property
 'cacheManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found   at
 org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:476)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:512)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:506)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1523)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 55 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot
 convert value of type
 [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager] to required
 type [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager] for property 'cacheManager': no
 matching editors or conversion strategy found  at
 org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:287)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:461)
```

Comment: Have you defined an interface for the bean?

Comment: <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache"/>

 <!-- EhCache library setup -->
 <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:config-location="classpath:conf/ehcache.xml"/>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have too little indirection in your setup. The config extract in your comment seems to match what's [documented](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html).

So I would suggest editing your question with your full Spring configuration to make sure you do not have other elements causing this error.

The error comes from where you want to `consume` the cache manager instance. In order to get to the backing `CacheManager` of Ehcache, you need to access `EhCacheCacheManager.getCacheManager` from your `cache-manager` bean.
The bean `com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0` expects the property `cache-manager` to be of a different type. Maybe that bean source - a library I assume - needs to be updated to match the version of Spring.